# Is it possible to select json data with where clause statement?

Tags: php, json, sorting

I have a problem with my JSON data. I have a string like this:

```
  data: [
    {
     groupid: "1449550897156TWTJ3UJNUR0CPTQ",
        voting_id: "14510478525898WTJUQX2FEJF0BU",
     answer_name: "081911112222",
     answer_code: "1",
     answer_content: "Hoka2Bento",
     datetime: "2015-12-25 19:51:12.075"
     },
     {
     groupid: "1449550897156TWTJ3UJNUR0CPTQ",
     voting_id: "14510478525898WTJUQX2FEJF0BU",
     answer_name: "085718733340",
     answer_code: "0",
     answer_content: "Hanamasa",
     datetime: "2015-12-25 19:52:42.862"
     },
     {
     groupid: "1449550897156TWTJ3UJNUR0CPTQ",
     voting_id: "14510478525898WTJUQX2FEJF0BU",
     answer_name: "081911113333",
     answer_code: "1",
     answer_content: "Hoka2Bento",
     datetime: "2015-12-25 20:19:51.643"
     },
     {
     groupid: "1449550897156TWTJ3UJNUR0CPTQ",
     voting_id: "14510478525898WTJUQX2FEJF0BU",
     answer_name: "087815254524",
     answer_code: "2",
     answer_content: "Korean Barbeque",
     datetime: "2015-12-25 20:30:46.418"
     }
     ],
```

I want to select `count` data with the parameter `answer_name = 1`. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: you need to loop json array.

Comment: Is is answer_name = 1 or answer_code: "1"?

Comment: do you want the count in  js?

Comment: use json_decode() and you will get array and  implement functionality as per what result you want into array.

Comment: @AmitShah yes i've been loop my json array

Comment: @PradeepSanjaya sorry, answer_code: "1" i think

Comment: Please post your attempts what you have tried so far

Comment: @user3040610 i want to count with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run this code,

```
<?php    
$data = '[
        {
         "groupid": "1449550897156TWTJ3UJNUR0CPTQ",
            "voting_id": "14510478525898WTJUQX2FEJF0BU",
         "answer_name": "081911112222",
         "answer_code": "1",
         "answer_content": "Hoka2Bento",
         "datetime": "2015-12-25 19:51:12.075"
         },
         {
         "groupid": "1449550897156TWTJ3UJNUR0CPTQ",
         "voting_id": "14510478525898WTJUQX2FEJF0BU",
         "answer_name": "085718733340",
         "answer_code": "0",
         "answer_content": "Hanamasa",
         "datetime": "2015-12-25 19:52:42.862"
         },
         {
         "groupid": "1449550897156TWTJ3UJNUR0CPTQ",
         "voting_id": "14510478525898WTJUQX2FEJF0BU",
         "answer_name": "081911113333",
         "answer_code": "1",
         "answer_content": "Hoka2Bento",
         "datetime": "2015-12-25 20:19:51.643"
         },
         {
         "groupid": "1449550897156TWTJ3UJNUR0CPTQ",
         "voting_id": "14510478525898WTJUQX2FEJF0BU",
         "answer_name": "087815254524",
         "answer_code": "2",
         "answer_content": "Korean Barbeque",
         "datetime": "2015-12-25 20:30:46.418"
         }
         ]';

        $array=json_decode($data);
        $count = 0;
       foreach($array as $arraydata)
       {
           if($arraydata->answer_code==1){
                $count++;
           }
       }

       echo "Count is" .($count);
 ?>
```

This way you will get all the answer count where code is = 1

please let me know if you need further help.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: please mark the answer as correct, so that other people gets the benefit for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,decode the json data in php.

```
 $array=json_decode($data);

   foreach($array as $arraydata)
   {
    $count[] = $arraydata['answer_name'];
   }

   echo "Count is" .count($count);
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback, but i want to add where clause in my json data, in my case i want to count with answer_code: "1"